# Is it possible to instruct Spring-WS to generate a WSDL containing wsdl:fault?

Tags: java, spring, wsdl, spring-ws

Here is another question that hasn't been answered at [Spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133191) yet.

I have an annotated endpoint that throws a custom exception that it's annotated with @SoapFault

But the WSDL, that is created dynamically, doesn't show a wsdl:fault in the wsdl:operation neither exists an xs:elementName for that exception.

Is it possible to instruct Spring-WS to dynamically generated the optional fault elements within the operations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined the exception xsd in the [servlet-name]-servlet.xml file

Like this -

```
<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="user" portTypeName="User"
        locationUri="/userService/" targetNamespace="http://test.nl/wsdls/userservice/2011/04">
        <sws:xsd location="classpath:/exception.xsd" />
        <sws:xsd location="classpath:/base.xsd" />
        <sws:xsd location="classpath:/user.xsd" />
        <sws:xsd location="classpath:/userservice.xsd" />
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

You see the exception xsd is there in the tag. So you have to define it.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://it-essence.xs4all.nl/roller/technology/entry/spring_ws_and_exception_handling1)

look at the Part1 link in topic XSD in above link.

Regards

Anshul Katta